# await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules in loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

FYI The api calls work fine as i change the SECRET to the real key.

I understand the error but not sure if I can solve this problem.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve. I am getting all dog breeds through a API call. This works fine and the array comes in after await. Now what I am trying to do is to loop through all the dog breeds and get information about the country they are from from another API. Than it tells me that

> await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

I cant have it at the top as I rely on the other result. How can this be achieved?

````
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function getCountry(breed){
    const countryOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com/location/country/'+breed.origin,
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'SECRET',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };
      await axios.get("https://countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com/location/country/'+breed.origin",countryOptions);
}

async function GetDogs(){
    try{
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://dog-breeds2.p.rapidapi.com/dog_breeds',
            params: {limit: '2'},
            headers:{'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'SECRET',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'dog-breeds2.p.rapidapi.com'}
          };
    const dogBreeds = await axios.get("https://dog-breeds2.p.rapidapi.com/dog_breeds",options);
    dogBreeds.data.forEach((breed)=>{
        const country = await getCountry(breed);
        console.log(country);
    })
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
};

GetDogs();
```
````

Comment: The short answer is stop using forEach, it's not a useful construct. You have to pass a function to forEach, that function is not async and wouldn't do what you expect even if it were. Use `for(const breed of dogBreeds.data)` instead and remove `forEach` from your toolbelt!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `async` function as a callback to the `forEach` method.

```
dogBreeds.data.forEach(async (breed)=>{
  const country = await getCountry(breed);
  console.log(country);
});
```

---

As mentioned in the comments you can use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to stay in the same `async` scope of the current function block.

```
for (const breed of dogBreeds.data) {
  const country = await getCountry(breed);
  console.log(country);
}
```

---

But you might want to do something with the result from `getCountry`.

**Do be aware the `getCountry` does not return anything.

So the the resolved `Promise` will yield `undefined`.**

If you fixed that than maybe using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `dogBreeds.data` array might be more useful in combination with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make the queries in parallel. The result will be an array of countries.

```
const countries = await Promise.all(dogBreeds.data.map((breed) => getCountry(breed)));
```